# In the Ubuntu SDK, is there a way to view all global variables in current project?

Tags: application-development, programming, ubuntu-sdk, qml, qt-creator

In the Ubuntu SDK, is there a way to view all global variables in current project? Working on one of the core apps, and I want to figure out if any global variables have been defined for the current time.